# Integromat - How to parse error message from custom API service

Tags: javascript, make.com, integromat-apps

I set up a custom app on Integromat that integrates a custom API for a delivery service.

Some of the module, sometime, got an error due to wrong address (es. wrong zip code). The API response's body has the specific problem in the `body`, but during the scenario, if the error happens, I only got the Integromat error which has no extra data at all, so I have to *rerun manually* the scenario using Integromat dev tools to read what was the problem.

Reading here [Error handling with different error structures in my custom Integromat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64114653/error-handling-with-different-error-structures-in-my-custom-integromat-app/71125119#71125119), I figure out to use a custom function to parse the response body

```
function parseErrorMessage(body) {
    if ('string' === typeof body.data)
    return JSON.parse(body.data)
}
```

but I didn't understand how to catch the 3 fields that hold the data: `errorFieldCode`, `errorTypeCode` and `errorMessage`.

The function is called in the module with this snippet:

```
  "response": {
    "output": "{{body}}",
    "error": "{{parseErrorMessage(body)}}"
  }
```

I would like to use those data in a module in the error handling path.

How should I edit the function above to parse the body into the 3 field it contains?

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXVJZ.jpg) where you can see the module having an error, the response body with the info I need to understand the error immediately (violet border), and the output of the module instead (orange border).

I am not able to manipulate the response body, since for Integromat is and error and it populates the output field with its data.

Comment: What does `JSON.parse(body.data)` look like when you call it? If it's an object containing the fields you need, then you're good, right?

Comment: The response body is an object, but I cannot use the fields inside in other modules.
The sole fields I could use in an error handling path, are the one provided by integromat which are `error.type`, `error.detail` end `error.message` and contain only the server response, usually `error 500`.

Comment: This is the error from the function: `Function 'parseErrorBody' finished with error! Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Is the function called `parseErrorBody` or `parseErrorMessage`? Also, there doesn't seem to be a `data` string in the `body` object, I think you're looking in the wrong place or not passing the correct `body` argument to that function.

Comment: The function is called `parseErrorMessage`, my mistake for using the wrong name. I edited the main request with extra info. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the `body` from the Intergomat dev tools tab, can you show another screenshot with the request and its response in the regular Network tab of the browser?